# The easiest way to access an object's single own property?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have an object which will only have one property (own property).  What is the easiest way to access that property's value?

Something like:

```
value = obj[<firstProperty>];
```

I know I can write a function or a for loop to do this but am asking if there is a shorter way.

```
for (p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
       value = obj[p];
    }
}
```

I won't know the name of the property up front.  I only know that there will only be one property directly on the object.

Comment: Fix the design of the data.  Objects with one unknown property name are usually a sign of a poor design choice somewhere along the line.  A single piece of data with an unknown property name does not belong in an object.  If you want to just store a single unknown key and value, then just put them in an array `["unknownKey", value]` and you can directly access each.

Comment: I'll bet you.  Show us the overall context and I'll be extremely surprised if what you describe is the best way to design it.

Comment: And what makes this case exceptional?

Comment: The reason Javascript doesn't have a built-in way to do this is because there are much better ways to express that data structure that Javascript does support directly.  You could even use two known property names to store your two unknown values `{propname: "unknownKey", value: val}`.  I'd rather see people improve to a better design that doesn't have this problem than implement a hack to work-around the design.  But, if you don't care to change the design, that's your choice I guess.

Comment: @ChrisGciso - if you really want to explain, you'd have to show code and actual data structures.  The words alone are hard to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like

```
var value = obj[ Object.keys(obj)[0] ];
```

getting the keys with `Object.keys` and the first (and only) key with `[0]`

Comment: @SLaks - Sure, why not, I just like `shift()`, does it matter ?

Comment: Because mutating the array is slower

Comment: @SLaks - yes, a function call less I suppose

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys for reference

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var value = obj[keys[0]];
```

We can make it shorter

```
var value = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
```

Comment: @ChrisGciso - no, second !

Comment: @adeneo, ha ha ha :)  actually I didn't see your answer while posting this. But it looks like  you are the first :)

Comment: and that's fine, you go, it doesn't really matter to me that much which one is accepted, it just seemed  like a strange comment from the OP